# Does the operator $\sum_i x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ have a name?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

This appears in Euler's homogenous function theorem.
Does it have a commonly-used name?

Answer (score 7):

I call it *the Eulerian derivation*. A less algebraically-minded person might say *Eulerian operator*.

Answer (score 3):

It is called the *homogeneity operator* on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator#Notations), not to be confused with the *Del* operator (further down the page). It's also a linear functional on the tangent space at any point of an $n$-manifold.

Answer (score 0):

It is also the expression in fibered coordinates of the $\textit{Liouville vector field}$ $Z$ on the total space $E$ of an arbitrary vector bundle $\pi:E\to B.$
$Z$ is defined as the infinitesimal generator of the action $\phi$ of $\mathbb{R}$ on $E$ by homotheties $\phi_t(u)=e^t.u$